# локальный сервер shiny

Tags: r, shiny

Товарищи, здесь есть кто-нибудь кто запускал shiny приложения в локальной сети без установки shiny сервера. На сколько я понял для этого нужно в команду `runApp()` дописать `host=мой ip, port=номер доступного порта`. То есть

```
runApp(host = 192.168.1.1, port = 5050)
```

Но при таком запуске браузер выдаёт ошибку 502. При этом при запуске на `127.0.0.1` приложение работает.
Теперь я пытаюсь понять это моя ошибка, или настройки сети не позволяют запустить приложение подобным образом?

Comment: Попробуйте оставить 127.0.0.1, а в строке браузера другой машины локальной сети войти по 192.168.1.1:5050. При этом 192.168.1.1 - точно адрес компьютера, где вы пытаетесь запустить приложение?

Comment: не помогло, видимо всеже без установки shiny сервера не обойтись

Comment: Порт на машине открыт?